# LLDB regex not recognizing \w+ with image lookup

Tags: ios, regex, lldb

I'm playing with LLDB with a simple app that has PhotosUI linked. Here's the command I'm running: `image lookup -rn '\+\[\w+' PhotosUI`. This is not giving me anything.

However, when I use `image lookup -rn '\+\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]+' PhotosUI`, I got many matches, one of which is

```
Summary: PhotosUI`__59+[UIViewController(PhotosUI) pu_currentViewControllerStack]_block_invoke
```

This is just one example that I totally expect `'\+\[\w+'` to also match. Did I miss something? This is the LLDB version I'm on:

```
lldb-1103.0.22.10
Apple Swift version 5.2.4 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.9 clang-1103.0.32.53)
```